# How to pass ref from forwardRef into a custom hook in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to implement useIntersection hook, the code works but I have problems with TypeScript:

```
import { MutableRefObject, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function useIntersection<T extends HTMLElement, U extends HTMLElement>(ref: MutableRefObject<T>, nodeCallback: () => U) {
  useEffect(() => {
    function callback([entry]) {
      ref.current.style.opacity = entry.isIntersecting ? '0' : '';
    }
    const node = nodeCallback();
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, {
      root: node
    });
    observer.observe(ref.current);
    return () => observer.unobserve(ref.current);
  }, [ref.current]);
}
```

I found somewhere that the result value from useRef is generic MutableRefObject. But I'm not able to use this hook with forwardRef

```js
import { forwardRef } from 'react';

const DownArrow = require('@site/static/img/down-arrow.svg').default;
import styles from './index.module.css';
import useIntersection from '@site/src/hooks/useIntersection';

export default forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, {}>(function MoreIcon({}, ref): JSX.Element {
  useIntersection(ref, () => document.querySelector('footer'));
  return (
    <div className={styles.arrow} ref={ref}>
      <DownArrow />
    </div>
  );
});
```

I got an error:

> Argument of type 'ForwardedRef' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MutableRefObject'.
> Type '(instance: HTMLDivElement) => void' is not assignable to type 'MutableRefObject'.

I also tried with `RefObject` (that is also exported from React) but got similar error.

Answer (score 0):

```
const MyComponent = (): JSX.Element => {
  const handleRef = (ref: HTMLDivElement | null) => {
    console.log('success');
  };
  return (
      <div ref={handleRef} />
  );
};
```

guess like this it should work

the `ref` is just a callback function

try like this:

```
import { MutableRefObject, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function useIntersection<T extends HTMLElement, U extends HTMLElement>(el: HTMLDivElement | null, nodeCallback: () => U) {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null!)
  useEffect(() => {
   ref.current = el;
}, [el])

  useEffect(() => {
    function callback([entry]) {
      ref.current.style.opacity = entry.isIntersecting ? '0' : '';
    }
    const node = nodeCallback();
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, {
      root: node
    });
    observer.observe(ref.current);
    return () => observer.unobserve(ref.current);
  }, [ref.current]);
}
```

this with ref available in and out:

```
import { forwardRef, useImperativeHandle } from 'react';

const DownArrow = require('@site/static/img/down-arrow.svg').default;
import styles from './index.module.css';
import useIntersection from '@site/src/hooks/useIntersection';

export default forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, {}>(function MoreIcon({}, ref): JSX.Element {
  const innerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null!);
  useImperativeHandle(ref,() => innerRef.current)
  useIntersection(innerRef , () => document.querySelector('footer'));
  return (
    <div className={styles.arrow} ref={ref}>
      <DownArrow />
    </div>
  );
});
```

Comment: this is because there is no current yet, the current is a result of useRef

Comment: ref accept a function but this is not the type of the ref object.

Comment: i guess, you suppose to write a handler yourself, otherwise you have to define useRef above useIntersection, and pass it along

Comment: @jcubic added you a case to test, otherwise similar workflow is over here [Link](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-use-measure/blob/8639e5a93d60930159dc83743780ce4787fe90bb/src/web/index.ts#L147)

Comment: Lol seems it's a `HTMLDivElement | null`

Comment: But why I can't pass the ref into the hook it works in JavaScript, this doesn't look right.

Comment: `useRef`, and `ref` aren't same thing, the `ref={ref}` is an actual element instance, and useRef produces a storage that is a stable reference (persisted on rerenders). so useRef is like create persisted storage

Comment: the difference between useState and useRef, that setState will produce rerender, and setting ref.current = anything would not

Comment: @jcubic, lol my bad, i you wanted to pass ref to hook and forwardRef... added you a way

Comment: I hope this is no the only way, this look horrible. You just add new API and new ref to make TypeScript happy.

Comment: this so called `merge refs` i think it was even more horrid before useImperativeHandle, you had to use package for this...

Comment: Thanks for your time. I will wait if there are no other answers. Because useImerativeHandler is for modification of the ref to expose the component API outside. So it looks like misuse of the React API to fix TypeScript bug.